# Turning off "Disable touchpad while typing" doesn't work (KDE)

Tags: kubuntu, touchpad, kde, lenovo

For reference, I'm running Kubuntu 18.04 on a Lenovo T480s. My question is sort of twofold:

1. Unchecking "Disable touchpad while typing" has no effect, even if I reboot my machine afterwards. I want to play some games and disabling the touchpad while typing is super inconvenient.
2. Would it be possible to write a script to toggle this setting on and off automatically when certain specified programs are running? How would I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears Kubuntu 18.04 is lacking a package. I had the same problem, and found the commands `synclient` and `syndaemon` which should supposedly fix it. However, none of these existed on my system, but I noticed they came from the same package. Try running

```
sudo apt install xserver-xorg-input-synaptics
```

and then reboot.

After having installed that, I recalled I had some touchpad problems after installing 18.04. Specifically, the touchpad was a lot less sensitive than it used to be, and a lot of touchpad settings were disabled. After installing that package, the touchpad is back to normal, and the settings are enabled again

Comment: this fixed it for me in Kubuntu 19.04 as well as fix centre-click-paste which i couldn't disable any other way. Surprised this isn't installed by default with KDE